# How to use fullcalendar with my django app?

Tags: python, django, fullcalendar

I have downloaded fullcalendar. I want to use this app with my django application. I

changed the following files..

1) Views.py (added the function to open the fullcalendar default.html file)

2) urls.py (passed the url)

I have copied the default.html file and other files in templates folder of my django app.

When I double click default.html, I can see the calendar. But through my django app the

calendar is not working. I am getting a blank page.

I am not getting any error. But the calendar is not displayed.

Comment: Have you enabled jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to insert calendar tags to your html page. It looks like

```
{% fullcalendar_css %}        
{% fullcalendar_print_css %}        
{% fullcalendar_jquery %}
{% fullcalendar_jquery_ui %}
{% fullcalendar_javascript %}

{% calendar_init calendar_config_options %}
```

Also, you should add `fullcalendar` in `installed_apps` of settings.py file. You can refer the below link for more info: https://github.com/rodrigoamaral/django-fullcalendar